# how swapping of two elements in a string can be done in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a string of english alphabets and i want to swap first element with second and so on. I am using this code:

```
for a = 1:25;
b= 1;
k(a)= k(a+b);
end
```

I don't know whether its a right approach or not. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Swapping means first element must have the data of second element and second element must have data of first.

In your code you assigned first element the data of second element but you dind'nt do it the other way around.

```
 i=0;
 k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
 b=1;
 for a= 1:5
   t=k(a+i);
   k(a+i)=k(a+b+i);
   k(a+b+i)=t;
   i=i+1;
 end
```

Comment: You could make this a bit cleaner by just replacing `b` with `1` everywhere. No need for a variable. :)

Comment: This is overly-convoluted code. Variable i can be replaced by loop variable a, the length of the loop should depend on the length of k, not just putting a constant value.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming the array has an even length.

```
k = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
temp = k;
k(1:2:end) = temp(2:2:end);
k(2:2:end) = temp(1:2:end)
```

The result I get is

```
k =
badcfehgjilknmpo
```

---

**EDIT**: Luis Mendo mentioned an even better way:

```
k([1:2:end 2:2:end]) = k([2:2:end 1:2:end])
```

Comment: Very nice and clean. +1.

Comment: Or just `k([2:2:end 1:2:end])`

Comment: Even better! @LuisMendo You should make that an answer.

Comment: But that's just a minor change in yours... feel free to incorporate it if you want (+1 already)